# Anyway to load RDL report content into a WPF FlowDocument or similar?

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, flowdocument, reportviewer2008

I would like to know if someone have created a RDL report (running it in Reporting Services), and loaded it into a WPF component like FlowDocument.

Since RDL is just a XML, perhaps there's a way to parse the result and avoid using this WindowsFormsHost in order to use the Report viewer control.

Would be really nice to have another control rather than this Report Viewer within WindowsFormsHost integration.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDL is XML, but very complicated XML. What you want is basically the ReportViewer rewritten in WPF. Not a small task at all.

One thing that springs to mind is requesting the report directly from the server and capturing the returned HTML, and embedding that HTML in a WPF control that can render it. But I've never tried that.

Generally speaking, so far, there is not a good solution for mixing Reporting Services and WPF/Silverlight.

Comment: Indeed that would be possible! If we can catch the returned HTML and load it into a WPF control, that would be really good. The problem might be only the paging and zooming behavior.

Comment: The problem is you get a static, dead report. You lose zooming, paging, searching, filtering, drill down, exporting, etc. Some of that stuff you can recreate yourself by making more calls to the server, most of that stuff you can't recreate at all. Overall it's a poor solution unless your report is very simple :( I've never done a (real) WPF app myself, so I've not experienced the pain of ReportViewer+WindowsFormHost that everyone talks about. But from what I can tell, it's still probably the best solution. I can say that MS is aware of this situation and is working on a real solution.